# WCF self-hosted console program won't host properly my service

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a self-hosted wcf service in a console app, when i use the visual studio debugger it works properly because when i hit **F5** it hosts the service automatically, but when i open the server `.exe` the service won't start giving **`EndPointNotFound exception`**, before implementing it as a **IIS** service i need to make console work in order to present it to my graduation exam

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.ServiceModel;
using BriscolaWCFdefLib;

namespace BriscolaWCFdef_Server
{
  class Program
  {
       static void Main(string[] args)
       {
            int control = 2;
            while (control == 2) {
            ServiceHost svcHost = null;
            try
            {                    
                Console.Clear();
                svcHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(BriscolaWCFdefLib.BriscolaService));
                svcHost.Open();
                Console.WriteLine("Gioco della briscola hostato su:");
                Console.WriteLine();
                foreach (var addr in svcHost.BaseAddresses)
                    Console.WriteLine("   {0}", addr);

                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Premere 1 per terminare il server, 2 per riavviarlo: ");
                control = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                svcHost.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.Error.WriteLine("Impossibile avviare il server: {0}", ex.Message);
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

here's the server code, anyone knows how to make my WCF service work with this self-hosted console program?

**EDIT:**

Here's the part System.Servicemodel

```
<system.serviceModel>
<services>
  <service name="BriscolaWCFdefLib.BriscolaService">
    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="BriscolaWCFdefLib.IBriscolaService">
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost" />
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/BriscolaWcfLib/BriscolaService/" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <!-- Per evitare la diffusione di informazioni sui metadati, 
      impostare i valori seguenti su false prima della distribuzione -->
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True" httpsGetEnabled="True" />
      <!-- Per ricevere i dettagli sull'eccezione per scopi di debug in caso di guasti, 
      impostare il valore riportato sotto su true. Impostarlo su false prima della diffusione 
      per evitare di diffondere informazioni sull'eccezione -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

Comment: You need to show us the `<system.serviceModel />` section of your app.config.

Comment: i've done it, how do you think this can help?

Comment: Check that the app.config file is set to "Copy Always" build action

Comment: How do you test it? What URL do you expect it on?

Comment: Can you open to the service url in same machine?